# How to push data from MySQL to HTML using Python

Tags: python, html, mysql, django

I want to poll an SQL database every hour and post the values to a website using python. However, I'm not sure where to start. Everywhere online either references PHP or pulls the data from a website to put into a database. I don't know PHP but i do know python. I've never used Django, would that be appropriate for pinging and displaying values?

Comment: Django can at least help create models by running `inspectdb` on your existing database. However, your question is still broad and does not show research effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django is great for creating database-driven web applications. If you just need a quick and dirty way to access MySQL via Python, then Django is overkill. You can use the Python module MySQLdb to query the database.

Example:

```
import sys
import MySQLdb

# Database configuration
config = {
    'host': 'localhost',
    'user': 'root',
    'passwd': 'password',
}

"""
Connect to MySQL, and attempt to select a database.
Then, query it.
"""
db = MySQLdb.connect(**config)

try:
    db.select_db('my_database_name')
except:
    print "Database selection failed."
    sys.exit(1)

cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("""
    SELECT * FROM my_table_name;
""")

rows = cursor.fetchall()

# Do something with rows of data.
# ...
```

Comment: The python MySQL module can be installed with pip using `pip install MySQL-python`